# Cuda Allocation/Memory tTime of Large Image

Tags: c, time, cuda, allocation

I'm performing image processing using CUDA. According to my timing, the allocation is taking the longest. One large image takes 0.00908 seconds to allocate and copy data into gpu memory.

Is this a normal amount of time? Am I doing something incorrectly?

```
  clock_t t = clock();  
  float * dData;
  unsigned int nBytes = width*height*sizeof(float);
  cudaMalloc( (void**)&dData, nBytes );
  cudaMemcpy( dData, Data, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
  t = clock()-t;
  printf( "Allocation to device: %f\n", ((float)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) );
```

Comment: Without more information about the size of the picture and the used GPU, my crystal ball is unable to retrieve informations...

Comment: Tell your crystal ball: Image is about 14 megabytes. GPU is GTX880M

Comment: You are measuring time about allocation and copying in the sample above. Is the result you wrote above from the sample, or did you really measure only the allocation?

Comment: If you're doing more than one image, overlap your communication and execution of the images by using asynchronous methods. http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

Comment: I don't see anything structurally wrong with your code.  I normally don't use `clock()`, but it may be working for you - its behavior is platform dependent.  14 MB of data should take less than 3ms  to transfer, and you are measuring 9ms, so that suggests the `cudaMalloc` is taking 6ms, which seems long.  I ran a slightly modified version of your code on a linux system for test and got ~4ms.  Example is [here](http://pastebin.com/W0qVgZAu)  Be sure to do some other cuda operation, such as `cudaFree(0);` before starting your timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're compiling in release and not debug. Values are in JEDEC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
// main routine
int main ()
{
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    for(size_t size=32; size<1024*1024*1024; size*=2){
          float* d_Data;
          float* h_Data = new float[size];


          cudaEventCreate(&start);
          cudaEventCreate(&stop);
          cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

          cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_Data, size*sizeof(float) );
          cudaMemcpy( d_Data, h_Data, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

          if(size>1024*1024){
              printf( "Allocation to device: %fms with size %dMB\n", time, (size*sizeof(float))/(1024*1024) );
          }else if(size>1024){
              printf( "Allocation to device: %fms with size %dKB\n", time, (size*sizeof(float))/1024);
          }else{
              printf( "Allocation to device: %fms with size %dB\n", time, size*sizeof(float) );
          }
          delete[] h_Data;
          cudaFree(d_Data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting times of:

```
Allocation to device: 0.017504ms with size 128B
Allocation to device: 0.012608ms with size 256B
Allocation to device: 0.462656ms with size 512B
Allocation to device: 0.386432ms with size 1024B
Allocation to device: 0.492512ms with size 2048B
Allocation to device: 0.409568ms with size 4096B
Allocation to device: 0.419648ms with size 8KB
Allocation to device: 0.402144ms with size 16KB
Allocation to device: 0.562240ms with size 32KB
Allocation to device: 0.460480ms with size 64KB
Allocation to device: 0.409376ms with size 128KB
Allocation to device: 0.492864ms with size 256KB
Allocation to device: 0.611424ms with size 512KB
Allocation to device: 0.577376ms with size 1024KB
Allocation to device: 0.722240ms with size 2048KB
Allocation to device: 1.174336ms with size 4096KB
Allocation to device: 0.995552ms with size 8MB
Allocation to device: 2.030592ms with size 16MB
Allocation to device: 3.876384ms with size 32MB
Allocation to device: 7.414432ms with size 64MB
Allocation to device: 15.325792ms with size 128MB
Allocation to device: 31.763008ms with size 256MB
Allocation to device: 65.624481ms with size 512MB
Allocation to device: 133.767838ms with size 1024MB
Allocation to device: 272.001404ms with size 2048MB
```

On K20x and 8-core Ivy Bridge Xeon